# How to create a function that takes an xexpression OR a container?

Tags: c++, xtensor

I'm a bit lost in xtensor types. I want to create a function that can accept either an expression or a container. How do I do that?

i.e.:

```
auto multbytwo(WHATGOESHERE x) {
    return x * 2;
}

xt::xtensor<double, 2> a = whatever;
auto b = a + 3.0;
auto c = multbytwo(b);
// now c should NOT be a container, it should be an un-evaluated xexpression.
```

...and like I said, I'd like the multbytwo function to work correctly if it's argument is an evaluated container, or an 'unevaluated' xexpression. Is it even possible? I'd like to pass the expression WITHOUT evaluation into a temporary, if the argument is an expression. My understanding is that if WHATEVER is `xtensor` then it will evaluate the expression, and I don't want that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with xtensor, so I won't hazard to post an answer. But you can do partial specialization with templated structs to get compile-time dispatch based on the argument type.

Comment: Yup, that's one way to solve this. But I still need to know what the type of "a + 3.0" above is. I actually do know it: "xt::xfunction<xt::detail::multiplies, const xt::xtensor_container<xt::uvector<double, std::allocator<double>>, 2, xt::layout_type::row_major, xt::xtensor_expression_tag> &, xt::xscalar<double>>". But wow that's a mouthful. That can't be the answer.

Comment: @Colin So the type you would want to specialize for is `xt::function<whatever>`? As in `template<typename ... whatever> auto multbytwo(xt::function<whatever...> x)` (except that partial specialization works with structs, not functions)?

Comment: Thanks @JaMiT that actually is half the answer - I didn't actually know how to pass such an 'unevaluated expression' to a function - I guess the answer is via an `xt::xfunction`. I'm still interested in the answer to: can I make a single function that can handle both such an xfunction or an actual container. Is it even possible? Is there like a common base-class or something?

Comment: You can us `xt::xexpression`. See for example [this blog](https://medium.com/@johan.mabille/designing-language-bindings-with-xtensor-f32aa0f20db)

Answer (score 0):

Each expression type `E` (`xarray`, `xfunction`, etc) inherits from `xexpression<E>`. Therefore, you can make `multbytwo` a template function accepting this type, and downcast the argument before using it:

```cpp
template <class E>
auto multbytwo(const xt::xexpression<E>& x)
{
    return x.derived_cast() * 2;
}
```